# Yii2, redirect after login. Avoiding controller \ action \ behaviors

Tags: php, yii2

So we have some controllers. For example it will be AboutController, IndexController, AuthController and ContactController. They all extends custom AbstractController that has init() method:

```
public function init()
{
    if ($this->getUniqueID() != 'auth') {
        Yii::$app->getUser()->setReturnUrl(Yii::$app->getRequest()->url);
    }

    parent::init();
}
```

This init() will save current url as returnUrl. Affect of this is redirect after login on page user were looking at (some kind of alternative of ajax login).

As you can se we avoid "AuthController" but I have problem with another thing - it's behavior.

In ContactController (same as in base setup of Yii2) we have behavior 'CaptchaAction'. So when we open `/contact/index` our returnUrl will be `/contact/captcha?xxxx` and after login we will be redirected there (to `/contact/captcha?xxxx`) and this is a problem.

In this example I use `$this->getUniqueID()` or can `$this->id` but when (regarding manual) I try to use `$this->action` it return me always `null`.

So, question is... How to avoid some controller\action\behaviors in init() method, or maybe someone can suggest better solution of this question.

Comment: It duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100608/redirect-user-to-previous-page-after-auth-yii2

Comment: @TomaszKane there is no solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use beforeAction along with your init()

What i suggest is to keep your init() logic as it, and set a beforeAction to your contactAction.

Check out this [Link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#beforeAction()-detail)